# Can't get background behind background-color

Tags: html, css, positioning, background-image, background-color

http://jsbin.com/opopup/2/edit

If you view this link, you can see I have a navigation menu embedded within a `#header` div. The header is simply there to center the nav and provide a background colour and image. I am trying to achieve a "fixed" header that has the background-color ON TOP of the background-image. I can't seem to get it right, played with z-index and cascade with no luck. Any suggestions?

I can get it to display properly if you change the position to "absolute" for the `#header`

## Edit

Sorry here is a jsfiddle, I didn't realize jsbin allows live edits

http://jsfiddle.net/NuBUV/

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to not put the background color on the header, as the image div is a child object of this one.

I would add a second div to header with the background color, so you'll end up having one div with the nav and the background image and one div with the background color. You can then play with z-index and positioning to overlay the one over the other. You might have to set some opacity or something.

Answer (score 0):

Like JanR mentioned, the issue derives from the div being a child of the header element. You can either swap the elements that the color and image are on like so:

```
.blurry {
    background:url('http://colourlovers.com.s3.amazonaws.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/colorful_by_souhail88.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
}
.one { 
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

or add another div after your .one and use similar absolute styling to overlay the color ontop.

In the first case the .one element overlays the image background of the parent element (.blurry). In the second case one div following another will have the same effect if they're both position:absolute;

Answer (score 0):

See this http://jsfiddle.net/VjYAA/

You want to wrap the image background around the nav element, which will have the translucent background color.  You may run into problems with this on older versions of ie that don't do transparency.

Anyway, here's the relevant stuff -

HTML -

```
<div id="header" class='one'>
  <nav class="blurry">
    <ul>
      <li><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>About</a></li>
      <li><a>Services</a></li>
      <li><a>Works</a></li>
      <li><a>Rates</a></li>
      <li><a>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.blurry {
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
.one { 
  background:url('http://colourlovers.com.s3.amazonaws.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/colorful_by_souhail88.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
}
```

Comment: If you do this, then the header will not have the background-color overlay matching the nav

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean.  Did you look at my jsfiddle?  That fiddle has the background image with a translucent color overlay, and no absolute positioning is used.  If that is not what you are looking for, can you be more specific?

Comment: In your original post, you said that it should look like your jsfiddle after changing the positioning of the header to absolute.  My jsfiddle looks exactly the same as that.  Let me know if there's something I'm missing.

Comment: It does look and perform exactly the way I intended to create it. But the problem is that if you have a header that has a background image and no color overlay, and a nav within it that has both the image and the overlay, then it does not look uniform. I want the entire header to have the color overlay AND the background image. My problem is getting both to display in proper order of depth.

Comment: I think you may need to provide another example of what you're looking for.  The best way to approach a problem like this is to have nested divs (or, in this case, a nav inside a div) and put the background image in the parent div and the translucent image in the child div (in this case actually a nav, but you can easily wrap the nav in another div like here - http://jsfiddle.net/h2XKw/).  Maybe you can link to a site that has the effect you are trying to create?  Are you just trying to have a portion of the background image be covered by the translucent color?

Comment: Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/VjYAA/2/

Here I am applying what you suggested. But as you can see, the header background-color only spans the nav, which makes sense because thats where it was applied. I want it to apply all the way across, in other words as long as the header is.

Comment: See this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kv8NS/  Like I said in my previous comment, wrap the nav in a div with class 'blurry'.  Then just set that div to `{width:100%}`.  Width of 100% will expand the element to be the same width as its container element, which in this case would be the div with id 'header'.

Comment: Doesn't work because if I apply a filter such as a blur filter on the `.one` it will blur everything it contains, not just itself.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but the idea as stated in the original post is to have a background-color and background image on the same div, with the background underneath.